# Bash: exact match of a string with regex

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I have to do an exact match on a string with a regex. i have to realize this pattern:
toCheck must start with 2 occurrence of $str1, with max 1 occurrence of $str2. If toCheck match the pattern, i have to write $toCheck:success inside output, $toCheck:failed otherwise.

I wrote this regex:

```
regex="$1($1)+$2"
```

Using the site regexr.com, i inserted for example:

```
regex="lo(lo)ba"
toCheck="loloba"
```

It's a success.

On regerx.com, this match until the last ba:

```
toCheck="lolobaba"
```

but, on my bash code, it's a success.

This is the complete code:

```
toCheck="lolobaba"
regex="lo(lo)+ba"

if [[ $toCheck =~ $regex ]]; then

    echo "$toCheck:success" > output
else
    echo "$toCheck:failed" > output
fi
```

So, the question is: how to have an exact match between the string and the regex?

Comment: FYI: It match on http://regex101.com/

Comment: Your question is confusing: you can either have an exact match (stings are identical) or you can have a regex match (string matches the template in a regular expression). A string either matches a regular expression or it doesn't - there is no approximate match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get a success because the regex matches on a *portion* of it.

If you want an *exact* match, you need to anchor the pattern to the start and end of the line: `regex="^lo(lo)+ba$"`

- the `^` stands for the start of the string: nothing can be before the pattern
- the `$` stands for the end of the string: nothing can be after

In your original code, as the pattern is not anchored, the pattern matching does not care of what could be before of after, if at least a portion of the string validates the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What are the parenthesis for? must start with 2x $str1 and end with max 1x $str2

So it's

```
    if [[ $toCheck =~ ^$str1$str1($str2|)$ ]] ; then
        echo "$toCheck:success" > output
    else
        echo "$toCheck:failed" > output
    fi
```